# Is capacitor voltage coefficient a function of frequency?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, analog

I have learned that the value of capacitance in a capacitor can vary slightly compared to nominal based on the voltage across it. This is called voltage coefficient of capacitance (VCC) It is actually a polynomial with first and second order terms. The sources I've found online indicate it is mostly due to the characteristic of the capacitor dielectric.

My question is this: Is VCC a function of frequency? If you have a capacitor with an AC voltage (on top of a given DC voltage) at say 100 kHz, would the measured VCC be different compared to 1 kHz, or 1 MHz?

Comment: Yes and no. My guess is that YOU wouldn't even be able to measure the voltage coefficient of ANY capacitor. Because it is a very small effect, and generally not something that you need to worry about unless you are doing more advanced electronics designs. My guess is that since you are asking this question here you are probably nowhere near applications that require attention to these kinds of details. All that said, if you really want to know; Yes, the voltage coefficient of capacitors is frequency dependent, but we are talking about frequencies in the uHz/nHz (micro/nano-hertz) region.

Comment: ..A simpler answer would be NO, voltage coefficient of capacitors is not frequency dependent. And in the vast majority of applications even where you need to worry about voltage coefficient of capacitor this is a good enough approximation. However if you really want the full truth then yes there is some frequency dependence. This comes about because over time the dielectric of the capacitor becomes gradually more polarized (over the span of minutes, hours, days even YEARS!). Due to this very slow process you would see some dependence in the uHz/nHz range and below. But just FORGET ABOUT IT!

Comment: @Vinzent The voltage coefficient of some capacitor types (e.g. ceramic) [can be substantial in "normal" applications](https://www.niccomp.com/resource/files/ceramic/VoltageCoefficientofCapacitors-032012-R1.pdf), requiring attention from designers. It does not obviously follow from first principles that this shouldn't be frequency-dependent, and/or should be ignored. Or am I confused/mistaking this with a different phenomenon?

Comment: @nanofarad Interresting. I don't understand why you claim that; "It does not obviously follow from first principles that this shouldn't be frequency-dependent, and/or should be ignored" I don't see what is wrong with claiming that as a rule of thumb the frequency dependence of voltage coefficient of capacitors can be neglected.

Comment: @Vinzent I'm not saying that the claim is wrong. I'm saying that I'd be very interested in hearing a justification for the claim in a more full answer, explaining why it can actually be ignored (rather than a comment, which is limited in length and ephemeral)

Comment: @nanofarad That's a good point. To be honest I'm not sure that I can justify with great scientific rigour why I believe that the voltage coefficient of capacitors is not inherently frequency dependent. If you can provide an argument as to why it would be then I am equally very interested in hearing it.

Comment: @Vinzent I don't have one - I honestly don't know, hence I've marked myself as following the question so I get inbox notifications for answers.

Comment: @nanofarad All I really know regarding the subject is that; 1) I have never seen the voltage coefficient of a capacitor mentioned with respect to frequency, or with any notes/comments regarding frequency attached.. But however!; 2) I have read an article a while back about long term stability/drift of capacitors due to long-term polarization of the dielectric which caused 1/f noise (basically equating to a very VERY low-frequency dependence of voltage-coefficient). This is what I know and what I based my comment on. But I'm certainly no expert on this, perhaps I too can learn something new.

Comment: I have been researching this. I found an EDN article by Bob Pease that suggests the dialectric absorbtion issue is frequency dependent. This is releated to VCC because how much dialectric absorbtion you get is proportional to the DC voltage you charge the cap up to. Here is a link: https://www.edn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/1982-10-13_EDN_Pease-capacitor-soakage.pdf